# How to typescript function which uses localStorage

Tags: typescript

Whatsup guys!
I try to make the universal function using generics.

```
export const setLocStor = <T, U>(key: T, val: U): void => localStorage.setItem(key, val);
```

What's wrong?

here is link https://codesandbox.io/s/async-feather-lmwxu?file=/src/helperFunction.ts

Answer (score 0):

u should pass a string as `value` :

```
const setLocStor = (key: string, val: string): void => localStorage.setItem(key, val);
```

Then stringify the object :

```
  const res = setLocStor("key", JSON.stringify({ val: "val" }));
```

**EDIT**:
Don't want to stringify all the time ?

If your object always the same add object interface like this:

```
const setLocStor = (key: string, val: { val: string }): void => localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
```

If not u should use `any` :

```
const setLocStor = (key: string, val: any): void => localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
```

edited sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mestorf-xsfon

Comment: I wanted to not use JSON.stringify every time. What if a value will be just a string or number then I won't need to use JSON.stringify. In this case I should use it always

Comment: I can't use "any" cuz  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

Comment: and didn't know the value types?

Comment: If its object like this `{val:"val"}` with different name u can use ` [key: string]: string`!

Answer (score 0):

In localStorage, the key and value should be string. That is, `setItem()` method accepts first argument (which is the key) should be string and the second argument (value) should also be a string.

```
setItem(key: string, value: string);
```

Example:

```
let user={name: 'Anoop'};
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
```

Here all the items to be saved in local storage are saved as string. First we need to convert to string.

When we retrieve, it returns back the stored string and then we need to have the parsing logic.

Example:

```
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));
```

Comment: I wanted to not use JSON.stringify every time. What if a value will be just a string or number then I won't need to use JSON.stringify. In this case I should use it always

Comment: not required if its a string value. Its just a sample I have shared.

Comment: JSON.stringify is one more transformation. Why do it if value just string?

Comment: If the value to be saved is a string, then no need to stringify further. But, its an object or array, then we need to. So we can have a logic for the same.

Comment: if no need to stringify how to make function with generics? Cuz function can has object, then string, then number.